# How to Organize Numbers using Regular Expression/Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to a regular expression to use with javascript replace function that separe with a space each 2 number I type

Input Ex.: 01020304050607

Output Ex.: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07

How could I do it?

Comment: can you put sample of the data you have that you want to perform the regex on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/(\d{2})/g` should do the trick. Example:

```
> "021651984984984984".replace(/(\d{2})/g, "$1 ").trim()
"02 16 51 98 49 84 98 49 84"
```

Comment: It works when I put whole string but If I type number by number using event on change. It gets a lot of spaces :(

Comment: @Rafael What do you mean? Are you trying to change something in an `input`?

Comment: Yes I want to use it in textarea

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer by clicking the outline of the checkmark next to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var numbers = "0203040506";
var numbersString = numbers.replace(/([0-9]{2})(?=.)/g,"$1 ");
```

Comment: What is the `(?=.)` part of the expression for?

Comment: @nnnnnn that is to keep it from returning things like "02 03 04 05 06 "